# Serializers not displaying foreign key data

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

My serializers are not showing related Models. I mean the models that have got many-to-one relationship. Please see the code below. Forgive my English.

Completely confusing me please help. I am new to django. I am trying to save my Draft js ContentState to the database. I have made the Post model a Foreignkey to my Block models. But When I try to retrieve the data using django-rest-framework serializers the blocks are not displaying.

Same applies with the Blocks I tried to serialize them on their own but the inlineStyleRanges and entityRanges data is not coming up.

````
#models.py
class Post(models.Model):
    created_by= models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cat= models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Block(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    key = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    text = models.TextField()
    type = models.CharField(max_length=90)
    depth = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class InlineStyleRange(models.Model):
    block = models.ForeignKey(Block, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    offset = models.IntegerField()
    length = models.IntegerField()
    style = models.CharField(max_length=90)

class EntityRange(models.Model):
    block = models.ForeignKey(Block, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    offset = models.IntegerField()
    length = models.IntegerField()
    key = models.IntegerField()

class Data(models.Model):
    data = models.TextField()

class EntityRangeData(Data):
    enityrange = models.ForeignKey(EntityRange, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

#Entity map here we go


class EntityEntry(models.Model):
    key = models.IntegerField()
    block= models.ForeignKey(Block, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=90)
    mutability = models.CharField(max_length=90)

class EntityEntryData(Data):
    entityentry = models.ForeignKey(EntityEntry, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

```#Serializers.py```


class EntityEntryDataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):


    class Meta:
        model = models.EntityEntryData
        fields = "__all__"

class EntityEntrySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    data = EntityEntryDataSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = models.EntityEntry
        fields = "__all__"


class EntityRangeDataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):


    class Meta:
        model = models.EntityRangeData
        fields = "__all__"


class EntityRangeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    data = EntityRangeDataSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = models.EntityRange
        fields = "__all__"





class InlineStyleRangeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):


    class Meta:
        model = models.InlineStyleRange
        fields = "__all__"


class BlockSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    inlineStyleRanges = InlineStyleRangeSerializer(many=True, required=False)
    entityRanges = EntityRangeSerializer(many=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = models.Block
        fields = "__all__"





class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    blocks = BlockSerializer(many=True, required=False, read_only=True)


    class Meta:
        model = models.Post
        fields = "__all__"
````

The output be like

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "created_by": 1,
        "cat": 2
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Block` model does not have attributes called `inlineStyleRanges` or `entityRanges`, so you should either use `related_name` in the ForeignKey field or you could specify a `source` argument in the serializer.

```
inlineStyleRanges = InlineStyleRangeSerializer(many=True, required=False, source='inlinestyle_set')
entityRanges = EntityRangeSerializer(many=True, required=False, source='entityrange_set')
```

You might have to include both nested serializers in `BlockSerializer.Meta.fields` as well. Instead of `"__all__"`,  use a list:

```
fields = ['id', 'post', 'key', 'inlineStyleRanges', 'entityRanges']
```

Comment: Suppose if i have more number of fileds, is there a way to pass `__all__` + `['inlineStyleRanges',  'entityRanges']`